# How to determine a script's location from the script's code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In struggling with a solution to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234215/where-are-scripts-loaded-after-an-ajax-call) I've run into another, related issue: how can I determine what the location of a running script is? (no, it's not `document.location` as that will tell you the location of the page including the script)

so, with:

**- a.html -**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/my/path/myscript.js"></script>
```

**- myscript.js -**

```
var myLoc = document.location; // what to use instead?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get script path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161159/get-script-path)

Comment: What sort of answer do you expect; the URL of the JavaScript file?

Comment: Is the script your trying to find actually in the page as a `script` tag or is it dynamically loaded in through ajax? if it's the latter I'm not sure you can

Comment: @DavidThomas, what I need is something that's available whilst the script is running that I can use to correlate against the array of scripts loaded and generally available as `$('script')`

Comment: @Chris, it's the latter (if you look at the link I included above you'll see where I'm coming from) but I'm building the script tags at runtime before the code runs and I can include any sort of information in the tag itself... what I don't have is a way to tell which of the entries in the array of scripts corresponds to the currently running script (and no, it isn't the last one added - unfortunately, otherwise I'd be done)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the answer to this is two-fold: 1) if the script was loaded by a  tag directly, one can use RightSaidFred's approach consisting of picking up the last entry in the list of scripts, 2) for scripts that are loaded in a page that was loaded via ajax, the solution is the plugin at: [Where are scripts loaded after an ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234215/where-are-scripts-loaded-after-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

If you can select the script, you can get its `src`.

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

var loc = scripts[ 0 ].src;
```

This gives you the src of the first `script` element found.

You can use jQuery to do it too.

```
var loc = $('script').eq(0).prop('src');
```

or for older jQuery versions:

```
var loc = $('script').eq(0).attr('src');
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
         type: 'get', cache: false, url: '/svc.html',
         success: function(h) {

             var d = document.createElement('div');
             d.innerHTML = h;

             var scripts = d.getElementsByTagName('script');

             alert( scripts[ scripts.length - 1 ].src );

             $('#main').html( d.childNodes );
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: if you read through the problem I was trying to solve originally, you'll understand this is not viable